# tensorflow convnet batch normalization example

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any documentation, example from tensorflow on how to use batch normalization layers in ConvNets?

I have seen some examples on the internet but some are incomplete (https://gist.github.com/tomokishii/0ce3bdac1588b5cca9fa5fbdf6e1c412 refers to unavailable my_nn_lib) and others deal with fully connected layers only.